# show SoftVideoEncoderOMXComponent failed log on android

Tags: android, c++, camera, android-camera

when I button Clicked. start capture camera preview.

when user button click, set `width, height, framerate, bitrate`

FrameRate, bitrate is a constant , but width, height is

```
//global variable
private static int mWidth;
private static int mHeight; 

private void init() {
    Point point = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);

    mWidth = point.x;
    mHeight = point.y;
}
```

width is `mWidth` and Height is `mHeight` set.

and I try build.

but `beginning of crash` message.

```
 A/SoftVideoEncoderOMXComponent: frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/omx/SoftVideoEncoderOMXComponent.cpp:467 CHECK((height & 1) == 0) failed.

                                                                                   --------- beginning of crash
 A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8299 (le.h264.encoder)
 A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
  A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android-x86/android_x86/x86:6.0.1/MOB31E/cwhuang09130303:userdebug/test-keys'
 A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
 ABI: 'x86'
 pid: 3944, tid: 8299, name: le.h264.encoder  >>> com.example.unno.mywebrtc <<<
  signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
  Abort message: 'frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/omx/SoftVideoEncoderOMXComponent.cpp:467 CHECK((height & 1) == 0) failed.'
   eax 00000000  ebx 00000f68  ecx 0000206b  edx 00000006
   esi 9f239980  edi 00000002
    xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000007  xss 0000007b
 eip b72e4096  ebp 0000206b  esp 9f238e70  flags 00000202
 backtrace:
  #00 pc 00085096  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
 #01 pc 00081278  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+70)
   #02 pc 00027265  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+36)
  #03 pc 00020a44  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+80)
   #04 pc 0000d863  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+128)
  A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0002f8c6  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so      (_ZN7android28SoftVideoEncoderOMXComponent20ConvertRGB32ToPlanarEPhjjPKhjjjb+518)
 A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0002fcb1  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so (_ZNK7android28SoftVideoEncoderOMXComponent20extractGraphicBufferEPhjPKhjjj+993)
 A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000d946  /system/lib/libstagefright_soft_avcenc.so (_ZN7android7SoftAVC13setEncodeArgsEP21ive_video_encode_ip_tP21ive_video_encode_     op_tP20OMX_BUFFERHEADERTYPES6_+774)
 A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000db0c  /system/lib/libstagefright_soft_avcenc.so
 A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0002b23a  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so (_ZN7android22SimpleSoftOMXComponent17onMessageReceivedERKNS_2spINS_8AMessageEEE+378)
 A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0002cebf  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so (_ZN7android17AHandlerReflectorINS_22SimpleSoftOMXComponentEE17onMessageReceivedERKNS_2spINS_8AMessageEEE+95)
 A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0000c9b9  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android8AHandler14deliverMessageERKNS_2spINS_8AMessageEEE+41)
  A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00010f32  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android8AMessage7deliverEv+114)
  A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0000de0f  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android7ALooper4loopEv+463)
  A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 0000e803  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android7ALooper12LooperThread10threadLoopEv+35)
 /DEBUG:     #15 pc 00014afc  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+418)
  A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 0001421f  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN13thread_data_t10trampolineEPKS_+122)
  A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00080723  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+56)
  A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 000219b2  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+25)
  A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 00017116  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
  A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
  E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe

                                    --------- beginning of system
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/a0940a5/media/libstagefright/omx/SoftVideoEncoderOMXComponent.cpp

this `SoftVideoEncoderOMXComponent.cpp` full source site.

I think `height` problem. , so I try set `mHeight -1` .

and I build, success program.

why set `mHeight` ?

thanks.
Have a Happy February.